# How to add a C# generic type constraint on another generic base class?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I've read the MSDN documentation on C# generic type parameter constraints several times, but I cannot figure out how to do this, or determine if it's even possible.

Say I have a generic base class like this:

```
public abstract class Entity<TId> { ... }
```

This abstract base class does not have any type constraints, `TId` can be anything -- a struct, class, etc.

Now say I have a generic interface method, and I want to constrain the generic types on the method to the above class:

```
public interface ICommandEntities
{
    void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : ?????;
}
```

I can get this to compile:

```
public interface ICommandEntities
{
    void Update<TEntity, TId>(TEntity entity) where TEntity: Entity<TId>
}
```

...however then I need to explicitly add both T1 ant T2 generic args when executing the method:

```
commander.Update<AbcEntity, string>(abcEntity);
```

If possible, I would like to make the compiler infer everything, so that I can execute the method like this:

```
commander.Update(abcEntity);
```

Is this event possible? So far the only way I can get it to work is by adding an empty, non-generic base class above the generic base class and using it as a type constraint on the method:

```
public abstract Entity {}

public abstract EntityWithId<TId> : Entity { ... }

public interface ICommandEntities
{
    void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : Entity;
}

commander.Update(abcEntity);
```

... but then I end up with a pretty useless class that acts as a marker interface. Is that the only way to get away with this type of generic class & interface method design? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: `void DoAbc<TForInterface>(BaseClass<TForInterface> impl);` would work, but I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: What I do not understand is the use of `T2` if it is neither an input paramether nor a return value.

Comment: Have you considered making the interface generic?

Comment: What about `void doAbc<T1>(BaseClass<T1> impl)`?

Comment: @all, I will update the question to be less "generic"

Comment: @SJuan76, `T2` (or `TId` after my edits) is not an input or return value for the interface method, it defines a property type on the `Entity` class, which is the constraint for `T1` (or `TEntity` after my edits).

Comment: In your updated example, I don't understand why you want your update to operate on two generic type when you have a base class. `void Update<TId>(EntityWithId<TId> entity);` is a good enough constraint, no? `EntityWithId` is an `Entity`, no need to put a generic constraint on an additionnal type argument.

Comment: As is already stated above, for your generic method, the way you have it, you need to supply the 2nd generic argument for for the generic abstract class.  There is no way this could be inferred.  One option may be to make the interface generic (for TId).

Comment: @SimonBelanger, you are saying that the interface method does not need any type constraints, no?

Comment: @danludwig If the argument of your method is `EntityWithId<TId>`, you don't have to because the argument on your `EntityWithId` class doesn't have one. The type argument can be more restrictive, but can't be less. Because `EntityWithId<T>` _is an_ `Entity`, you satisfy your base class constraint previously put on type argument.

Comment: @all thanks for the great comments and answers. This led me to ask another related question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/20220120/304832, hope to see some of you there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking that it compiles, I will upgrade it to an answer.

From your question and comments, you want the parameter to be `Entity<Something>`. You do not need to use the parametrized types directly as a type, it can be use to parametrize a parameter.

So just do

```
 public void Update(Entity<T1> entity) where ....
```

Comment: ... Ok I think I'm getting it now, doing it this way, the interface method does not need any generic type constraints, if I use the base class as the method arg. Is that right?

Comment: What you do is define what type of parameter you want. You want `Entity<X>`, so all you need to parametrize is `X`. Don't forget the issues of covariance, maybe it is worth marking the type parameter as `in`.

Comment: The generic on `Entity` has no constraints though. It can be a `string`, `int`, `long`, or it can be a `XyzCompositeId` class. I don't think I want to apply any co- or contravariance here.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you. `X` will have the constraints defined in `Entity` parameter types (none in the code you provided). Also, you can specify the constraints that you want as  `IEntityCommand.Upload` parameter types. I do not know if you are asking for confirmation that there are no constraints or if you want to define any.

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion. I do not want any additional constraints on the interface method. I just don't want any code to be able to invoke the method passing an instance of a class that does not derive from `Entity<X>`. So you are correct, I could make X covariant for this method.

Comment: One correction: I do not think you will have to deal with covariance. If you use `Update(Entity<X>)` and `Update(Entity<SubX>)` with inference typing, the runtime will likely identify them as "different" as `Update(Entity<X>)` and `Update(Entity<Y>)` would be. The only possibility of covariance issues would be by expliciting the types (v.g. `Update<X>(Entity<SubX>)`).

Answer (score 2):

The simple option would be to change the signature of `ICommandEntities`:

```
public interface ICommandEntities
{
    void Update<TId>(Entity<TId> entity)
}
```

This effectively gives the same constraint that you're after.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you should just make the parameter type `BaseClass<T>`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        ITest x = new TestClass();

        Console.WriteLine( x.GetTypeArgTypeFrom( new BaseClass<int>() ) );

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

public class BaseClass<T>
{
    public Type GetTypeArgType()
    {
        return typeof( T );
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    Type GetTypeArgTypeFrom<T>( BaseClass<T> bct );
}

public class TestClass : ITest
{
    public Type GetTypeArgTypeFrom<T>( BaseClass<T> bct )
    {
        return bct.GetTypeArgType();
    }
}
```