# How should I apply generics to the following interface method, given current code?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

This is a follow-up to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20218383/304832) where I received a lot of great comments and answers. That question brought up this one.

Say I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Entity<TId> : IEquatable<Entity<TId>>
{
    public TId Id { get; protected set; }
    // plus implementation of IEquatable, GetHashCode override, etc.
}
```

The other question I asked had to do with how to implement an interface for entity commands, which now looks like this:

```
public interface ICommandEntities
{
    void Create<TId>(Entity<TId> entity);
    void Update<TId>(Entity<TId> entity);
    void Delete<TId>(Entity<TId> entity);
    void Reload<TId>(Entity<TId> entity);
}
```

Before, I was trying to figure out how to do this with generic type constraints to restrict the method arguments to be of type `Entity<TId>`. Answers to the previous question told me I don't need to do that, I can just use my abstract class as the method argument.

However, I still don't understand how can I do the following, where the interface method has no arguments?

```
public interface IQueryEntities
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>() where TEntity : ???????;
}
```

When Invoking this method, I only want to pass a single generic argument like so:

```
var queryable1 = queries.Query<EntityAbc>();
var queryable2 = queries.Query<EntityXyz>();
```

... where the entity classes might look something like this:

```
public class EntityAbc : Entity<string> {...}
public class EntityXyz : Entity<int> {...}
```

How can I constrain the interface method so that it only allows classes that extend from `Entity<TId>` to be passed as a generic argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your interface to be generic:

```
public interface IQueryEntities<TId>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>() where TEntity : Entity<TId>;
}
```

and then when you implement it:

```
public class EntityAbc : Entity<string>, IQueryEntities<string>
```

or maybe event his:

```
public abstract class Entity<TId> : IEquatable<Entity<TId>>, IQueryEntities<TId>
```

---

So to update to reflect the comments. Making that interface generic is still the approach. If you didn't want the entities implementing the interface, no problem, you could do this:

```
public class QueryEntities<TId> : IQueryEntities<TId>
{
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : Entity<TId>
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Using that might look like this:

```
var queries = new QueryEntities<string>();
queries.Query<EntityAbc>();
```

But, you're not going to be able to send *any entity* into that interface unless you make the method itself receive the `TIn`. If you were to make the method itself generic like that the code would be this of course:

```
var queries = new QueryEntities();
queries.Query<EntityAbc, string>();
```

the interface for that looks like this:

```
public interface IQueryEntities
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity, TId>() where TEntity : Entity<TId>;
}
```

but you don't want that.

Comment: I don't want any `Entity` classes to implement the `IQueryEntities` interface. The implementation of the `IQueryEntities` interface will come in another class, and should handle any value for `TId`, not just strings or ints.

Comment: @danludwig, so how do you expect to pass an *entity* in as the generic type and yet constrain the `IQueryEntities` which is implemented on some unknown class that is completely unrelated to the code given?

Comment: @danludwig, as a side note, making the `IQueryEntities` interface generic would still the the approach. Even if another class implemented it. That class would be something like `public class Queries<TId> : IQueryEntities<TId>`.

Comment: Well, maybe I don't know enough about generic constraints to know if what I want to do is possible. If possible, I want the compiler to prevent someone from calling `QueryEntitiesImpl.Query<ClassThatDoesNotInheritFromEntity>()`

Comment: @danludwig, by making the implementer generic, or the method as well, that's possible. Notice the constraint that I've placed on the `Query` method in the interface - `where TEntity : Entity<TId>;` - and so it is constrained. The class will have to at least inherit from `Entity`.

Comment: Right, but like you said, I would have to have different implementations of IQueryEntities for each TId, correct? If that's the only solution, I may need to revert back to my previous solution, which had a non-generic abstract base class above the generic abstract base class...

Comment: @danludwig, you'll need to build the *right IQueryEntities* interface for the *entity* you're going to send it **or**, make the method generic instead (the last example I gave you) in which you can send in any entity because you're going to specify the `TIn` when you call `Query`.

Comment: So you are saying that I can't have one interface implementation for all entities, and get away with not specifying the second generic arg when invoking its methods. If you are saying that cannot be done, that is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @danludwig, yeah that won't be able to be done because there is no parameter being passed into the method to help it *infer* the type. Therefore, since *inference* can't occur you have to specify the type yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41970/discussion-between-danludwig-and-michael-perrenoud)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got right your question, just a wild guess, would this work for you?:

```
IQueryable<Entity<TId>> Query<TId>();
```